# What is better practise in high-performance computing: passing a struct of data into a function or a set of variables?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, hpc

Imagine that I have a struct that contains a set of variables that describe an object, which is a grid in my case. I was wondering, if I have a function that only uses a subset of the grid, whether there are any performance differences in the two variants of the `computational_kernel` functions below. The kernels are the same, except that the one in which the struct is passed has to extract the `itot`, `jtot` and `ktot` from the struct before heavy computations are done.

```
struct Grid
{
    int itot;
    int jtot;
    int ktot;

    int not_used_in_kernel1;
    int not_used_in_kernel2;
    int not_used_in_kernel3;
    int not_used_in_kernel4;
}
Grid grid;

// Code that initializes the grid values...

// Variant 1
computational_kernel(double* array1, double* array2,
                     const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot);

// Variant 2
computational_kernel(double* array1, double* array2,
                     const Grid& grid);
```

Comment: Had you benchmarked?

Comment: That depends very much on compiler, compiler version, optimization flags, CPU model and architecture, and probably other things as well.

Comment: Also, technically speaking you're not passing a structure in the second version, you are passing a *reference* to a structure.

Comment: @Ginden I have not benchmarked it, I was just curious whether the dereferencing of a complex structure has costs if you only use a few variables that are part of that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `computational_kernel` is a function that does a lot of work internally and is invoked few times the difference between the two versions is infinitesimal. The second version has just the extra cost of dereferencing 3 values, than the rest is identical, and you presumably have to do such dereferencing anyway before invoking the first version.

I would definitely use the second form for compactness reasons: if you are defining object-oriented data structures then use them in such a fashion (better encapsulation).

Comment: If there are no other costs in passing a struct by reference, compared to passing an integer by value, then I think I find this the most reasonable answer. Is dereferencing the struct as cheap as copying the integers?

Answer (score 2):

I think passing a struct is better for the code maintenence. if you add new fields to your grid, you will only have to change the function. But passing a set of variables you will have to change the function and every call to the function.

Comment: Good considerations, though counter balancing the benefit you mention, passing the `Grid&` makes `computational_kernel` useless unless you have a `Grid`.

Comment: @TonyD ...which is actually a good thing! You minimise the risk of invoking `computational_kernel` with wrong inputs.

Comment: @claudv: an implementation of "variant2" that calls "variant1" would provide the convenience and input assurances you mention - albeit at a small runtime cost if both functions weren't inlined - while keeping the increased reusability and testability of variant1.  Anyway, the devil's in the detail... how much potential reuse there could be, what else is in `Grid` that's e.g. painful to initialise or costly in memory and could be skipped for test cases etc..

Comment: @TonyD So you mean using variant 2 as a wrapper for variant 1 and keep both available. Sure!

Comment: I disagree with this answer, because even though Grid might change, I do not have to pass extra variables to that kernels than the one I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that passing a reference to a struct as in the 2nd variant would probably be more efficient performance-wise. On the 1st variant the caller will need to push the 3 int variables on the stack while on the 2nd variant all it has to push is a reference (a pointer) to the struct and do the stuff there. The performance impact is of course bigger if you had more than 3 variables to pass.

Comment: *"need to push the 3 int variables on the stack"* - not necessarily, some compilers/ABIs pack many arguments into registers before falling back on the stack, in which case passing them in registers should never be slower than passing the grid reference (assuming the called function's guaranteed to use the 3 fields).  When passing the grid reference the called function may need to do a from-cache/memory read of the fields, even if the caller had those values in registers (assuming the called function's not inlined).